# C - Ways to free() groups of elements in a hash table?

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm currently fiddling with a program that's trying to solve a 2d rubix cube.The program is using a hash table as a memory of sorts where it saves different categories of information and it's runs on repeat. From run to run there are certain categories of information I'd like to free/remove instead of freeing the whole table at the end of each run (which is what I'm currently doing).

I've come up two ways and I'm unsure which to use. Either i basically make one array/stack for each of the categories where I save a pointer that i can later free. Or i make separate hash tables for all of the different categories and free each one at my discretion.

Are there other options? Some where i read about a pointer pool and I'm not sure what that might be. Any ides or helpful comments would be great!

Comment: Perhaps a heap of pointers to the hash table with a priorty of the time at which it was inserted?

Comment: *"I'd like to free/remove instead ..."* The key word there is `remove`. You can't free anything until you remove it from the hash table. And it's only one line of code to free the memory after removing the entry from the hash table.

Comment: a data structure should match the constraints of the data. a 'hash' does not match the constraints of a 2d array

Comment: Choice#1: do you need dynamic allocation? If not: use a static array.

Comment: Thank you guys for the input! I think I'll go with a few static arrays. But I'll probably try to to fit them into a jagged array. Gonna have to try how to do that with a struct. We'll see how that goes else I might post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have more memory or time ?) If you use hash table (include separate) then you need use if for check all element in your hash table. It is very more time. I think best way create second struct when you save object after create. For free all table you need run on simple array without check and use memory set zero for flush your hash table. You need little bit more memory but more effective work.